# String in struct. corrupted

Tags: c, struct

There is struct like this.

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};
```

And function which set's address.

```
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email) {
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    if(addr->set) die("Address already set");

    addr->set = 1;
    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Name copy failed");

    *res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
    if(!res) die("Email copy failed");
}
```

But first character of addr->name gets corrupted after this line.

```
*res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `if(!res) die("Name copy failed")` ... I smell PHP :D

Comment: `void die(const char *message) {
 if(errno) {
  perror(message);
 }
 else {
  printf("ERROR: %s\n", message);
 }

 exit(1);
}`
Am coming from PHP :)

Comment: There's no need to check the return value of `strncpy()`, because it *always* returns the value of its first argument. Always.

Comment: Also be aware that if `source` (`name`) is `MAX_DATA` characters in length `strncpy` will not add a NULL character at the end of `dest` (addr->name) for you.

Comment: 99.99% of the time strncpy is the wrong function to use. It's only in C because Ken Thompson wanted it for writing UNIX directory entries, which were 14 byte NUL-padded but not NUL-terminated fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strncpy` returns its first argument so after

```
char *res = strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
```

the variable `res` holds `addr->name` (equivalently, `&(addr->name[0])`) so when

```
*res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
```

is run it is the equivalent of

```
addr->name[0] = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);
```

This assignment is what corrupts the first char of `addr->name`. As Greg Hewgill says, you don't need to check or even save the return value of `strncpy`.

Comment: Note: If you need to ensure the string is null terminated, the 3rd argument to strncpy should be MAX_DATA - 1, and you should manually set the last char to 0. strncopy only inserts a null if the 2nd argument is shorter than the 1st's size.  An easier solution is to just increase the MAX_DATA constant by one, and then pass in MAX_DATA-1 as the 3rd argument, thus reserving space for the null termination.  Again, this presumes you will call functions that depend on null termination.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `strncpy()` function is not what you want here. Consider the call:

```
strncpy(addr->name, name, MAX_DATA);
```

In the event that `name` has `MAX_DATA` or more characters, this will copy the bytes from `name` into `addr->name` and will *not* NUL-terminate the destination. You have two general choices:

1. Manually NUL-terminate the result using code such as

   ```
   addr->name[MAX_DATA-1] = '\0';
   ```

   however, this is error-prone because you have to remember to do it each time.
2. Use a library function such as `strlcpy()` (usually available on BSD-derived systems, but not standard) that always NUL-terminates the destination, even if the source won't completely fit.

Comment: Note that strlcpy is not part of any standard and might not be available on all platforms (including Linux glibc).